# Как достать WebView из ViewPager?

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте.

У меня в активити имеется **ViewPager**, в который я посылаю две страницы.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
List<View> pages = new ArrayList<View>();
ViewPager viewPager  = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
View page1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.arhiv_page, null);
View page2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_page,null);
pages.add(page1);
pages.add(page2);
SamplePagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new SamplePagerAdapter(pages);
viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

В другом классе, в который я передаю данный **ViewPager**, мне необходимо добраться до **WebView**, располагающийся в **page2**. каким образом мне это сделать?
Я уже пробовал и WebView передать в класс, предварительно получив его в первом

```
  View page2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_page,null);
  newsView = (WebView) page2.findViewById(R.id.web_new);
```

но ничего не вышло, при попытке открыть url в принятом WebView, ничего не отображается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вопрос решен, был задан из-за двух часовых попыток это сделать, но в итоге, оказалось, что у SamplePagerAdapter есть поле pages, из которого можно достать нужную страницу и уже от туда получить WebView.